# SSRS Rendered in Sharepoint and Export Differences

Tags: sql-server-2008, reporting-services

I have a report that gets pulled and exported through sharepoint. Today I made some changes to one of the reports deployed those changes.  Now when I render the report in sharepoint everything looks correct. However when I export the report in CSV format the column names revert to the aliases from the sql query instead of what I put in the designer for them.

Has anyone experienced an issue like this?

Any help is appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have seen this issue in the past with XML export. This may help:

1. Select the column, then open the Properties panel (you can also hit F4 as a shortcut)
2. Change the **DataElementName** attribute
3. Try export to CSV again

You didn't specify which version of SSRS you are using. This is a screenshot in Visual Studio 2010 / SSRS 2012:

[image]